# How to buffer pyplot plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

TL;DR: I want to do something like

```
cache.append(fig.save_lines)
....
cache.load_into(fig)
```

I'm writing a (QML) front-end for a pyplot-like and matplotlib based MCMC sample visualisation library, and hit a small roadblock. I want to be able to produce and cache figures in the background, so that when the user moves some sliders, the plots aren't re-generated (they are complex and expensive to re-compute) but just brought in from the cache.

In order to do that I need to be able to do the plotting (but not the rendering) offline and then simply change the contents of a canvas. Effectively I want to do something like cache the

```
line = plt.plot(x,y)
```

object, but for multiple subplots.

The library produces very complex plots so I can't keep track of the `line2D` objects and use those.

My attempt at a solution: render to a pixmap with the correct DPI and use that. Issues arise if I resize the canvas, and not want to re-scale the Pixmaps. I've had situations where the wonderful SO community came up with **much** better solutions than what I had in mind, so if anyone has experience and/or ideas for how to get this behaviour, I'd be very much obliged!

Comment: If you don’t try to open them across versions of matplotlib you can pickle figures and reload them.

Comment: It's not quite what I'm looking for... I'm not trying to save them to disk (I'm actually trying not to save them), I don't know what variable needs to be plugged in and out of a figure to clear all of its subfigures but save the contents...